# System.Format.Exception c++ winforms

Tags: windows, winforms, c++-cli, forms

```
try
{
    easynumber = Convert::ToInt32(this->textBox1->Text);
}
catch (const std::exception & ex)
{
    MessageBox::Show(this, "Вы ввели не число!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons::OK);
    
}
```

учу с++ параллельно winforms, Нужно обработать исключение System.Format.Exception, данный способ не работает, пытался через просто if, тоже не помогло, вместо окна с обработкой, выходит окно стандартное, которое гласит о "необрабатываемое исключение в приложении"
************** Текст исключения **************

````
```System.FormatException: Входная строка имела неверный формат.
   в System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   в System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   в System.Convert.ToInt32(String value)```
   и т.д
````

не понимаю что не так, я вроде как обработал ошибку когда вместо числа которое с string конвертируется в int пользователь вводит букву/символ которую естественно не конвертировать..

Comment: `catch(Exception * e)`

Comment: @user7860670 компилятор ругался на *, заменил на ^ все заработало, спасибо!

Comment: [тыц](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1570504/winforms-c-Полное-отсутствие-понимания-и-внятного-руководства#comment2830407_1570504)